# One launch per 10 seconds

Tags: jquery

I'm creating a scroll down page auto load data. But when I scroll down the page getPosts function working more than one. When I `alert()` after function, there is no problem. How can I block multi launching when page scolling down?

```js
var _primary = 0;
var _second = 15;
$(document).ready(function() {
  getPosts(_primary, _second);
});

function getPosts(x, y) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      uidHash: "<?php echo md5($_SESSION['uid'].'pass_!_'); ?>",
      minVal: _primary,
      maxVal: _second
    },
    url: 'postloader.php',
    success: function(posts) {
      $('#postholder').append(posts);
      _primary += 15;
      _second += 15;
    }
  });
}

$(window).scroll(function goDown() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {
    getPosts(_primary, _second);
  }
});
```

Comment: where is your getData() function ? Are you saying your getPosts() fired multiple times ?

Comment: Yes, sorry i was wrote wrong. I'll edit now.

Comment: Follow @Zakaria answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add a flag `postsAlreadyCalled` like :

```
$(window).scroll(function goDown() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100 && !postsAlreadyCalled) {
    getPosts(_primary, _second);
    postsAlreadyCalled = true;
  }
});
```

So the function will be called just one time.

Hope this helps.

```js
var _primary = 0;
var _second = 15;
var postsAlreadyCalled = false;

$(document).ready(function() {
  getPosts(_primary, _second);
});

function getPosts(x, y) {
  console.log('Get data');
}

$(window).scroll(function goDown() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100 && !postsAlreadyCalled) {
    getPosts(_primary, _second);
    postsAlreadyCalled = true;
    
    setTimeout(function(){
        postsAlreadyCalled = false;
    },10000);
  }
});
```

```css
#test{
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, my function be called just once but what i want to do is after 10sec., i want to make my function is callable again.

Comment: Then you could add `setTimedout()` function thats switch the flag value to false after 10 seconds... check my update.

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery, check whether you have hit the bottom of page using scroll function. Once you hit that, make an ajax call (you can show a loading image here till ajax response) and get the next set of data, append it to the div. This function gets executed as you scroll down the page again.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
           // ajax call get data from server and append to the div
    }
});
```

#### OR Try this lib

http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/
Below is the simple way of calling a waypoints plugin and having the page load more Content once you reaches the bottom on scroll :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $loading = $("<div class='loading'><p>Loading more items&hellip;</p></div>"),
    $footer = $('footer'),
    opts = {
        offset: '100%'
    };

    $footer.waypoint(function(event, direction) {
        $footer.waypoint('remove');
        $('body').append($loading);
        $.get($('.more a').attr('href'), function(data) {
            var $data = $(data);
            $('#container').append($data.find('.article'));
            $loading.detach();
            $('.more').replaceWith($data.find('.more'));
            $footer.waypoint(opts);
        });
    }, opts);
});
```

#### OR

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo: Lazy Loader</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        #myScroll {
            border: 1px solid #999;
        }

        p {
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            padding: 50px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .loading {
            color: red;
        }
        .dynamic {
            background-color:#ccc;
            color:#000;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        var counter=0;
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height() && counter < 2) {
                appendData();
            }
        });
        function appendData() {
            var html = '';
            for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                html += '<p class="dynamic">Dynamic Data :  This is test data.</br>Next line.</p>';
            }
            $('#myScroll').append(html);
            counter++;

            if(counter==2)
            $('#myScroll').append('<button id="uniqueButton" style="margin-left: 50%; background-color: powderblue;">Click</button></br></br>');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myScroll">
        <p>
            Contents will load here!!!.<br />
        </p>
        <p >This is test data.</br>Next line.</p>
        <p >This is test data.</br>Next line.</p>
        <p >This is test data.</br>Next line.</p>
        <p >This is test data.</br>Next line.</p>
        <p >This is test data.</br>Next line.</p>
        <p >This is test data.</br>Next line.</p>
        <p >This is test data.</br>Next line.</p>
        <p >This is test data.</br>Next line.</p>
        <p >This is test data.</br>Next line.</p>
        <p >This is test data.</br>Next line.</p>
        <p >This is test data.</br>Next line.</p>
        <p >This is test data.</br>Next line.</p>
        <p >This is test data.</br>Next line.</p>
        <p >This is test data.</br>Next line.</p>
        <p >This is test data.</br>Next line.</p>
        <p >This is test data.</br>Next line.</p>
        <p >This is test data.</br>Next line.</p>
        <p >This is test data.</br>Next line.</p>
        <p >This is test data.</br>Next line.</p>
        <p >This is test data.</br>Next line.</p>
        <p >This is test data.</br>Next line.</p>
        <p >This is test data.</br>Next line.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I seen this library before, but that if section never returns true on my website.

Comment: Try this in my ans. $(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
           // ajax call get data from server and append to the div
    }
});

Comment: Glad I could help.If you think it's helpful please mark it as answer and vote up.  Thank you